# How to add a custom menu for google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

As a part of project requirement I need to add a custom menu (context menu) to the google drive right click options. 
As per my research google app script can help for creating a custom menu for google docs, google form and google sheet. However I haven't yet come across a way to add a custom menus for google drive.

I cannot use chrome extension as I need it to be all browser compatible.

Any ideas if it's even supported and possible.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I had to integrate an app with "Open With" option in Google Drive.

Apparently, context menus are not supported in Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom context menus in Google Drive. The custom menus you read about in Docs, Sheets, etc are added in the menubar at the top of the editor, not into the right-click menu.